# Kubuntu does not properly boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, kubuntu

I am trying to install Kubuntu on my laptop only no matter what I try, it is not booting after the installation. When I boot my laptop, I first see the Lenovo logo as usual and then the animating kubuntu logo. After a few secs, some text appears below the logo but only for a few milliseconds so I cannot read it. Then, the Lenovo logo is displayed again and it will infinitely hang on that state. Running it from a live USB works fine.

I tried different ways of installing and the main changes are in the partition system:

1. Create automatic partition by the installer AND install all updates after it is installed. This crashed the installer so I deselected update after installation and that made the installer atleast not crash anymore
2. I tried several times setting up a custom partition system. I create the following partitions: EFI, swap, ext4 (mount /), ext4 (mount /home). I also tried some installations with ext (mount /boot). [source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation]

None of this seems to make a difference.

When I enter the boot manager when starting up the laptop, an entry of Ubuntu is listed and also in the BIOS. I installed Linux mint (latest chinamon) and Fedora (Fedora KDE x86_64-32 ) before on the laptop so I don't understand why I can't get this working. I have to notice that I was able to sucessfully boot fedora but after an attempt to install the videocard driver, it started to show the same behaviour as Kubuntu now. The entire harddrive is for Linux. Windows is not installed anymore.

I also found some articles that it may be related to grub.I tried updating/installing grub via the live USB but that was not successful.

I downloaded this ISO file: kubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

**System information**

- Intel i7 processor
- 16 GB RAM
- Intel HD video card + NVidia GTX 840M 4GB
- 100Tb SHDD (8gb ssd part), brand Western Digital

Does anybody have a clue why it is not working?

Edit 1:
added system information

Comment: You haven't mentioned what release of Kubuntu you're talking about (nor any clues as to your Lenovo laptop, it's age or architecture). The Mint & Fedora information is also only helpful if you're specific as to versions (for comparison of software stacks which maybe a huge clue! but we can't know without being given the facts). Ubuntu releases are easy as all releases are *year.month* in format, but you've provided no specifics at all.

Comment: @guiverc You are right, my mistake. I just added it.

Comment: Two things: 1) verify your installation media to make sure it's valid; 2) wipe your hard drive before attempting the installation (don't manually make a bunch of partitions)

Comment: @Nmath I solved it. See my answer. It was a driver issue, not a partition issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem. In the Kubuntu installer, there is an option to install proprietary drivers which I always checked when installing. I unchecked that and now Kubuntu is able to boot. I rebooted several times, applied all updates and installed the proprietary Nvidia driver and booting still works.

Comment: Same problem, same solution