# Trouble with installing Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu

1. I downloaded Kubuntu 21.10 from official site, checked the SHA256 checksum in PowerShell, received 4A56CFC43E0F4EAD6B7E66B3DA67AB22D96C46DC090190A06D 2848B6E03FE02A
2. Then I created a bootable USB via Rufus, all on screenshots. Before that I formatted  my flash drive using FAT32 filesystem. I used [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview).
3. I the ejected SSD with Windows 10, because I had problems when installed Kubuntu with connected SSDs, only SSD for Kubuntu with 120 GB of free space and hard drive with some files stays in system.
4. In UEFI, I selected USB drive.
5. Restarted and installed Kubuntu, all steps on photos.
6. Have a screen with Motherboard, with working buttons Del or F11, then 2-3 seconds of totally black screen, then screen with Motherboard again, but without working buttons Del or F11 (press on them and nothing happens).
7. Go to UEFI, changed boot options, and had the same problem.

Screens: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmKx2.jpg

[image]

DxDiag: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3CcKRASwhgSNZAMysMlCUu0l_cIS45E/view?usp=sharing

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 12/20/2021, 16:59:28
             Machine name: DESKTOP-Q4IJ4P0
               Machine Id: {424C38C5-95E8-4377-A4A8-A817998DC9FB}
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19044) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: MSI
             System Model: MS-7816
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 04/01/15 11:17:33 Ver: V3.10B0 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670K CPU @ 3.40GHz (4 CPUs), ~4.0GHz
                   Memory: 12288MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 12216MB RAM
                Page File: 7225MB used, 7422MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\Windows
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
                 Miracast: Available, no HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: 1.0.8
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.19041.0928 64bit Unicode

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
           Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
        Manufacturer: NVIDIA
           Chip type: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
            DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
         Device Type: Full Device (POST)
```

I tried Rufus Partition Scheme "GPT" and Target System "UEFI (non CSM)", but nothing changed.

---

The problem was simmilar to: [Kubuntu does not properly boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281852/kubuntu-does-not-properly-boot?rq=1)
Don't select "Install third party drivers" and all will be ok

Comment: The Google Drive file doesn't exist. The screenshots however show the (or one of the) problem from the beginning. Rufus settings should be GPT/UEFI. And CSM disabled in UEFI to avoid wrongly installing in Legacy mode as you already did. And in addition to the instructions in the next comment you should also disable Fast Startup in Windows before proceeding (and keep the drive connected - you want to use its ESP).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: I fixed google drive. No, this isn't answer to my question, I want to install Kubuntu alone, not alongside with pre-installed Windows, I want install it on empty SSD and use it without Win10. Any options except BIOS OR UEFI in Rufus aren't available

Comment: If you want Kubuntu only then the mention of removing the Windows drive or anything related to it is irrelevant. Now, again, Rufus has different options and unfortunately the default isn't what you want for any machine from ~2012 or newer. You may use other tools like Balena Etcher that don't have that "problem" but then either you disable CSM in UEFI ("BIOS") or you select the proper option when booting the installer (the one with "UEFI:"). Please also [edit] the question to include hardware specifications.

Comment: What is in the Google Drive is irrelevant as the only useful information is about the graphics card. Make sure that you select the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, etc. so the Nvidia drivers are automatically installed.

Comment: I should choose in Rufus Partition Scheme "GPT" and Target System "UEFI (non CSM)"? It's only available option except MBR/UEFI

Comment: Exactly, that's what I said.

Comment: Ok, I tried this option, but nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132494/discussion-between-oleg-chaika-and-changanauto).